# Название сорта хризантемы и большие буквы

Tags: выбор-слов

Сорт хризантемы «предрассветный аю-даг». То, что в неспециализированной литературе сорта пишутся с маленькой буквы – это да. А как быть с Аю-Дагом в названии? Повышать его?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Некоторые названия могут иметь разные формы написания:

1. Прописная буква, без кавычек (в специальной литературе). 2. Прописная буква с кавычками (основная форма). 3. Строчная буква с кавычками. 4. Строчная буква без кавычек. Форма 3 и 4 фактически относятся к нарицательным существительным. Наличие кавычек в форме 3 говорит о том, что данное слово пока не является общепринятым термином, в отличие от формы 4.

Для названий  растений  обычно используются:

**Прописная буква, без кавычек** **(форма 1**, в специальной литературе): клубника Виктория, тюльпан Махровый ранний. Большинство представителей тюльпана Махрового раннего – потомки старинного сорта  Мурильо.

**Строчная буква с кавычками**. Эти же названия могут писаться в кавычках и со строчной буквы **(форма 3)**: клубника «виктория» –  неофициальное название.Через месяц Елена собирала клубнику «виктория» в плетеный туесок.

**Строчная буква без кавычек**. Распространенные и общепринятые названия цветов и плодов пишутся со строчной буквы и без кавычек **(форма 4)**:   иван-чай, анютины глазки, белый налив, китайка. Цветет иван-чай с июня по август.

**А теперь выбираем форму для приведенного примера.** В каталогах используется форма 1, в текстах, сязанных с темой цветов (описание выставок, например) формы 1 и 2, что видно из примера:

Выбираем принцессу бала хризантем 2020!

Что может быть лучше, чем увидеть  **Предрассветный Аю-Даг**, встретить Ялтинский рассвет или Весенний рассвет на дамбе Су-Ти? Несколько слов о хризантеме «Пять Звёзд». Она  вырвалась вперёд в очном голосовании, но в режиме онлайн на пятки пятизвёздочной красавице нынче активно наступают: «Bigoudi Purple», **«Предрассветный Аю-Даг»**, «Rayonante Bronze» и «Creamiest White».

Если это художественная литература, не имеющая никакого отношения к цветоводству, то можно, как я думаю,  использовать нарицательную форму 3: хризантема "предрассветный аю-даг". Но это нужно смотреть по тексту, что туда лучше подойдет.

Answer (score 1):

По правилам,  неспециальных текстах названия сортов растений, овощей, фруктов заключаются в кавычки и пишутся со строчной буквы (в том числе и имена собственные): клубника «виктория»; помидор «иосиф прекрасный»; яблоки «пепин литовский», «бельфлёр китайский», «шафран-китайка».

В специальной литературе в названиях сортов растений, овощей, фруктов, цветов первое слово (и все имена собственные) пишется с прописной буквы: крыжовник Слава Никольска, малина Мальборо, земляника Победитель, смородина Выставочная красная, яблоня Китайка золотая ранняя, слива Никольская белая, роза Мария-Луиза, фиалка Пармская, тюльпан Чёрный принц.

Если честно, мне тоже не нравится строчная буква в названии горы, этот сорт ведь точно назван в честь горной вершины. А почему бы нам не воспользоваться правилом спецлитературы? Мы же имеем в виду термин, ну вот как автомобиль "Волга"? Название от собственного имени - пишем с большой буквы. Во всех справочниках - с прописной и без кавычек. Бывает так, что спецтермин входит в общелитературный язык, мне кажется, подобное  название совсем близко к этому процессу. Я бы написала:  хризантема Предрассветный Аю-Даг, а если даже и с кавычками, тоже так, ведь с кавычками положение более свободное, это не будет ошибкой.